# Simulation in Multisim is taking a lot of time. Probably due to the signal multiplier(Modulator)

Tags: multisim

[image: Here is the circuit that I am using]In this AM modulator/demodulator circuit, I am trying to see the variations of output signal due to changes of frequency and phase of the carrier signal at the demodulator. All is working fine until the carrier frequency gets higher. For 100KHz it is working fine, for 1MHz it barely works, and for 10MHz(which I'm interested in) I have to go to dinner and come back to see a reasonable output at the oscilloscope. Are there any solutions you would suggest? I think the part that is taking a lot of time is the modulation/demodulation process.

Comment: My sim would take about 1 second to do that but I don't use multisim.

Comment: The part that is likely taking a lot of time is not the modulation / demodulation. It is most likely that the simulation step size for 10 MHz is much much smaller and the system may be running out of RAM for simulation. Compare the RAM usage and disk activity for the different cases. Or alternately, force the same step size (say, 1e-9) for all cases and check if the 100 kHz simulation is also as slow as the 10 MHz case.

Comment: What's the timescale that you are trying to simulate for? If it's for tens or hundreds of periods of the highest frequency, then it shouldn't take long. If it's more, the simulation time will increase accordingly.